# How to make custom jQuery-Validate Rule work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

This is my form:

```
<form class= "myForm" action="someAction" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="source" value="zions_direct" />
    <ul class="cf">
      <li>
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" class="text" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="text" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="input-email" placeholder="Email Address" class="text" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="submit" alt="Send My Form" target="_blank" value="SUBMIT" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I'm trying to create a jQuery-validate rule that checks firstName and lastName against a Regex and displays a message (while preventing form submission) when the criteria is not met (or the custom rule returns false):

```
function validator() {
  $.validator.addMethod('nameCheck', function(value, element) {
    return /^([a-zA-Z .'-]{3,80})+$/.test(value);
  }, 'Please type a valid name');

$('.myForm').validate({
  rules: {
    firstName: {
      required: true,
      name: true,
      nameCheck: true
    },
    lastName: {
      required: true,
      name: true,
      nameCheck: true
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  }
});
```

What am I missing? The built-in *email: true* works, but my custom one doesn't. I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: The `name` method is not part of the plugin.  Unless you've also created it with `.addMethod()`, that would definitely be a problem.

Comment: Check your Javascript console for errors.

Comment: @Sparky That was the problem, I had renamed 'name' to 'nameCheck' and forgot to delete this line before adding the rule. That's silly. But thanks, if you want to post an answer I can accept...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` method is not part of this plugin.  And I don't see anywhere in your OP that you've created it using `.addMethod()`, so this is going to get the validation stuck before it evaluates your `nameCheck` rule.

```
firstName: {
    required: true,
    name: true,  // <- what is this? 
    nameCheck: true
},
```